# Calling API using axios in react native getting 404 error when using params

Tags: react-native, axios

I am calling an api using axios. Below code is working fine

```
    <ButtonComponent
    label="SIGN IN"
    onPress={() => {
         axios
           .get(
             "http://example.com/Api/Users?email=abc@gmail.com&password=abc"
           )
        .then((res) => {
          console.warn(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn(error);
        });
    }}
  />
```

but when I send it with params instead of a complete string, it gives error "Request failed with status 404"

```
    <ButtonComponent
    label="SIGN IN"
    onPress={() => {
      axios
        .get("http://example.com/Api/Users?", {
          params: { email: { email }, password: { password } },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.warn(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn(error);
        });
    }}
  />
```

Please guide what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't this `params: { email: { email }, password: { password } }` be `params: { email: email, password: password }` or just `params: { email, password }`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put curly braces for parameters values.

```
axios.get("http://example.com/Api/Users?", {
          params: { 
                    email: abc@gmail.com,
                    password: abc 
                  },
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
axios.get('/api', {
  params: {
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  }
});
```